# How to print just message body from payload of a mail in python 2.7

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I am trying to print message but getting unwanted text. Not able to filter that.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import imaplib
import email
import re
p = re.compile(r'Server Status')

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('stbeehive.yxz.com')
(retcode, capabilities) = mail.login('abc@yxz.com','passwd')
print retcode, capabilities
mail.list()
mail.select('Inbox')
n=0
(retcode, messages) = mail.search(None,'(UNSEEN)')
if retcode == 'OK':
    for num in messages[0].split() :
        print 'Processing '
        n=n+1
        typ, data = mail.fetch(num,'(RFC822)')
        for response_part in data:
             if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                 original = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
                 print original['From']
                 print original['Subject']
                 if original.is_multipart():
                     message =  original.get_payload()[0]
                     print message
                     for line in message:
                         if p.findall(line):
                             print line
                 else:
                     print original.get_payload()

print n
```

When I am trying to print getting below message.I just want third line from this.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Server Status#XYZBSS##XYZ Running
```

I tried to filter "Server Status" by using re.compile in the above code but getting below error.

```
  File "./mail.py", line 27, in <module>
    for line in message:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/message.py", line 292, in __getitem__
    return self.get(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/email/message.py", line 358, in get
    name = name.lower()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Python 2.7 for this? New development should definitely target the recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: @tripleee unfortunately python3 is not yet approved in my org. So, I have to live with python2.7 for sometime.

Comment: Your org is pushing the limits here. By the original timetable, Python 2 would have been end-of-lifed already earlier this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the message this is mildly speculative, but it looks like you are extracting a body part with headers and all. You want to find the correct body part, then extract its payload.

Without an actual message to look at, there is no way to test this, but I'm guessing something like

```
             if original.is_multipart():
                 # Quick hack, should probably properly recurse
                 message =  original.get_payload()[0].get_payload()
             else:
                 message = original.get_payload()
             #print message
             for line in message.split('\n'):
                 if 'Server Status' in line:   # look ma, no regex necessary
                     print line
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Only one issue coming. The line contains more than 80 words. In one line its giving upto 77 words . Rest of the words are going to next line. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: It is probably encoded with Quoted Printable; it breaks long lines with "=" signs.  Do you see stray = in your message?

Comment: Python should purge any QP when you request the payload, but a reguar text/plain message should not usually have lines longer than 80 characters. Again, without seeing the message, we can only speculate. If the message is `format=flowed` it will be rendered as one line even if the message source is physically split over multiple lines; but Python will just see the physical lines.